# Why won't this script do anything in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, picasa

I could use another pair of eyes. This script does what I want in Chrome (renders a gallery of images from a google picasa web album), but doesn't render anything in IE8, can anyone see anything obvious?

```
    $(function () {
    var json_Photo_URI = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/111727095210955830593/albumid/5420114965919213729?alt=json&fields=entry(title, media:group)&thumbsize=75"
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: json_Photo_URI,
        success: function (data) {

            var photo_URL = "";
            var photo_Thumb_Url = "";

            $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
                $.each(item.media$group.media$content, function (i, item) { photo_URL = item.url; });
                $.each(item.media$group.media$thumbnail, function (i, item) { photo_Thumb_URL = item.url; });

                var photo_Description = item.media$group.media$description.$t;

                $('#gallery').append("<a href='" + photo_URL + "' title='" + photo_Description + "'><img src='" + photo_Thumb_URL + "'></a>");
            }); 

            $('#gallery a').lightBox({ txtImage: 'Photo', txtOf: '/' });
        }, dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

Comment: first thing I've noticed: missing ; in second line after url string..don't know..maybe

Comment: @gpasci as long as your code is on seperate lines you don't need semi-colons, just good practice to use them

Comment: no, not getting errors. and the missing ';' was a good catch, but didn't help.

Comment: Cross-domain security issues, perhaps?

Comment: @kolink: but would that only affect IE?

Comment: IE Caches remote AJAX calls which can cause problems with the request. See this question for more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013637/unexpected-caching-of-ajax-results-in-ie8

Comment: @E.J.Brennan It might if jQuery's attempting to use `XMLHttpRequest` (`dataType: 'json'`) rather than JSONP. jQuery [doesn't use](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js) the [`XDomainRequest` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx) needed for [IE8/9](http://caniuse.com/cors) to make cross-origin Ajax requests.

Comment: IE is calling the $.ajax error callback. Also here's a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/b36v5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
dataType : 'json'
```

with

```
dataType : 'jsonp'
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/b36v5/2/

Comment: That did the trick - thank you.  Here is a post that explained json/jsonp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683114/sending-jsonp-vs-json-data

Comment: @E.J.Brennan: This would make a great question. I remember reading about IE caching requests more aggressively. Specifying 'jsonp' deactivates the cache. You can read about this on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ under *cache*.

Answer (score 1):

It's about cross domain AJAX requests. The site you are trying to access correctly sets the `access-control-allow-origin: *` response header in order to allow AJAX requests for browsers that support CORS. And [IE supports CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS), partially. In fact in IE in order to support CORS you have to use a different object called [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as explained in the following blog post in order to achieve cross domain requests. Except that [`jQuery.ajax` doesn't support it](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) out of the box. And if you look more carefully in the bug ticket you will see that it is closed because [there are plugins](http://graphicmaniacs.com/note/getting-a-cross-domain-json-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8-and-later/) that allow to achieve that.