# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : getting while calling wcf rest service

Tags: jquery, wcf, rest

I am trying to call a wcf rest service by the following way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickMe').click(function () {
        $.ajax(
                    {
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8064/CarService.svc/carservice/car/1',
                        success: function (data) {
                            // $('#photo').append(data[0].Image);
                            alert("Yes");
                        }
                    });
    });
});
```

I am calling it from MVC3 application. When I hit this (localhost:8064/CarService.svc/carservice/car/1) url, then everything is ok. It gives me following data.

```
{"Id":"1","Image":{"Data":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,72,0,72,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,3,3,3,3,3,6,4,4,3,5,7,6,7,7,7,6,7,7,8,9,11,9,8,8,10,8,7,7,10,13,10,10,11,12,12,12,12,7,9,14,15,13,12,14,11,12,12,12,255,219,0,67,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,12,8,7,8,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,255,192,0,17,8,0,128,0,128,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,29,0,0,1,4,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,5,7,8,1,2,4,3,9,255,196,0,59,16,0,1,3,3,3,3,2,4,2,8,6,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,5,17,6,18,33,7,49,65,19,81,8,34,97,129,20,113,21,35,50,145,161,177,209,240,9,22,36,66,82,193,98,114,23,51,225,255,196,0,27,1,0,1,5,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,6,2,7,255,196,0,46,17,0,1,3,3,3,2,3,9,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,3,4,17,49,18,33,65,5,81,97,113,129,6,19,34,145,161,177,193,225,240,20,50,209,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,248,55,138,85,182,51,253,246,172,227,181,10,66,212,14,14,13,108,148,224,228,210,198,43,52,33,42,84,169,80,132,171,41,27,141,101,166,139,206,37,9,74,148,165,28,4,164,100,147,71,26,11,165,255,0,143,189,37,187,131,209,98,171,159,213,188,176,0,32,103,4,231,27,188,99,223,142,244,161,112,247,6,141,208,133,190,213,38,232,239,167,25,135,159,94,15,202,218,10,143,29,251,83,156,109,1,114,144,214,253,141,55,192,33,46,57,177,103,61,184,52,77,126,184,187,102,47,68,134,113,29,10,40,37,35,25,3,177,207,177,166,73,151,23,37,134,130,20,16,150,78,48,56,43,7,29,207,158,71,241,161,53,169,199,9,186,78,141,185,198,86,12,85,172,123,182,66,199,240,166,249,17,29,140,178,149,161,72,80,247,20,90,197,246,67,142,184,55,40,133,231,245,121,228,30,224,10,245,16,91,189,69,91,139,73,107,105,74,20,20,78,84,78,123,19,143,110,199,247,210,32,60,242,130,20,209,221,88,45,145,69,17,52,41,153,54,75,73,113,192,166,50,112,81,140,129,231,61,177,245,172,68,233,226,238,175,165,182,37,68,109,197,130,160,30,120,36,112,51,183,61,179,237,92,151,1,185,78,7,4,49,176,214,165,63,157,59,223,180,187,186,126,44,87,156,126,51,169,148,92,72,13,47,113,65,66,182,144,126,244,251,211,235,30,137,159,38,208,117,61,207,82,66,97,233,233,102,224,32,69,105,74,110,50,129,5,214,148,179,130,164,171,110,82,71,236,231,28,226,184,51,54,218,134,235,171,128,130,197,42,84,169,213,218,84,169,82,161,22,74,178,148,238,80,30,77,96,12,154,232,183,55,254,169,42,63,178,142,78,123,80,139,34,77,41,101,138,151,218,10,146,35,45,120,222,249,73,87,166,60,132,129,201,86,59,1,231,185,20,243,116,179,127,151,157,36,250,171,97,42,220,133,161,69,43,116,30,220,131,199,229,227,154,227,208,122,45,237,113,126,106,223,20,72,125,231,212,144,3,96,18,172,248,207,253,81,93,215,166,46,233,150,221,102,76,153,8,117,132,133,237,113,33,13,237,43,41,71,25,228,168,133,109,242,64,39,24,230,153,117,68,77,120,97,59,164,20,210,185,166,80,62,21,226,220,103,164,217,84,251,50,218,125,148,182,160,180,72,94,245,0,123,128,54,247,239,201,237,66,23,139,115,75,148,210,163,236,216,250,70,18,18,65,65,206,48,65,252,179,249,17,249,3,251,54,156,92,4,38,27,147,22,227,79,148,171,245,56,15,40,100,2,148,243,145,220,255,0,98,140,45,29,24,255,0,51,234,107,164,136,118,199,35,195,97,240,150,152,57,82,24,74,183,43,122,149,201,9,73,40,79,60,147,147,130,41,170,154,214,69,148,237,37,4,146,219,74,130,161,52,146,251,72,121,183,54,74,70,27,35,130,133,110,198,126,184,167,199,44,178,81,38,76,103,3,132,132,237,60,18,20,82,50,15,231,143,63,151,138,151,58,151,208,40,250,77,167,205,178,60,169,237,195,101,41,101,64,31,80,187,198,72,73,29,183,115,159,225,81,253,227,89,163,97,138,133,54,247,172,254,84,243,195,209,120,12,36,97,89,224,17,143,190,72,39,28,142,168,170,89,59,117,52,225,113,93,75,37,59,244,184,32,107,116,233,214,121,206,180,195,234,10,88,45,169,59,78,213,167,219,7,222,183,149,116,66,45,106,14,198,109,46,130,84,156,185,129,142,217,74,64,206,71,156,159,183,20,247,46,245,102,158,182,145,33,78,135,208,231,255,0,97,225,10,71,0,18,156,229,36,121,30,212,221,170,172,219,208,224,124,176,31,104,238,74,153,57,67,128,243,227,143,53,46,202,40,55,59,132,53,54,232,229,194,36,102,22,73,110,32,82,91,201,201,0,156,226,185,156,148,181,54,218,20,181,20,52,78,193,255,0,18,79,143,189,100,55,177,210,147,142,61,169,235,166,90,234,111,75,186,137,101,212,86,199,16,205,202,201,49,185,145,92,90,18,226,82,180,28,140,165,64,130,61,193,30,105,139,105,192,79,156,108,135,105,99,52,135,122,207,99,197,58,157,88,164,70,13,103,60,10,193,57,161,11,41,239,78,54,21,180,110,113,211,33,91,99,122,169,83,191,46,64,78,121,56,243,197,55,12,248,175,84,16,17,223,4,241,244,197,9,44,172,199,195,197,134,25,51,38,55,58,224,134,217,113,214,75,144,28,12,188,226,64,199,202,188,21,39,63,248,224,209,142,129,248,84,103,170,215,99,232,55,124,139,6,49,223,34,231,112,117,68,202,127,60,54,195,28,97,8,78,1,90,142,78,62,194,29,232,6,185,187,233,123,107,77,91,216,140,151,11,138,82,94,148,112,144,162,64,200,79,251,143,208,114,127,141,88,125,27,241,57,125,208,114,63,29,169,34,77,114,221,25,5,107,68,104,201,75,206,167,184,218,209,41,193,206,126,222,107,37,95,21,88,153,239,132,238,113,222,222,75,79,211,167,163,17,50,41,193,183,150,223,52,113,11,224,182,211,101,211,49,3,151,4,173,109,157,238,74,146,194,66,215,144,79,203,236,79,35,34,157,17,113,211,157,41,130,171,93,177,137,50,229,5,250,104,244,145,185,79,17,193,57,207,61,187,251,98,188,245,55,87,166,245,134,211,6,214,221,189,205,44,223,224,69,226,52,219,166,75,247,6,125,127,75,99,109,160,148,32,165,106,111,59,148,73,222,156,12,115,66,182,89,234,233,109,214,227,124,153,167,175,26,158,53,149,44,200,184,41,181,6,99,68,105,247,118,161,107,9,193,59,149,201,202,149,192,228,1,222,13,53,33,144,134,212,184,184,158,1,31,124,125,118,86,21,53,194,32,93,72,208,214,142,72,63,108,249,109,186,60,211,189,27,234,86,183,178,77,190,91,186,99,170,238,54,152,41,114,68,137,241,210,149,250,40,66,20,227,139,244,214,82,165,108,109,10,90,130,114,118,164,144,21,218,169,207,196,166,135,129,173,35,179,169,180,172,134,110,72,145,133,60,212,53,7,50,149,126,203,161,35,231,79,63,180,20,6,59,241,146,43,232,222,166,248,223,191,66,153,211,109,111,161,180,205,153,51,227,88,220,182,8,243,161,42,75,41,138,218,158,100,38,107,45,169,181,150,138,94,82,210,146,176,78,51,192,39,53,10,87,248,103,89,228,233,145,45,205,83,53,185,193,181,20,166,61,173,184,233,111,42,82,182,128,92,81,9,27,136,0,147,132,224,120,205,91,205,29,29,4,173,45,144,180,242,50,8,176,236,118,249,170,168,95,91,212,98,45,123,3,155,144,112,65,185,238,7,217,82,98,181,54,230,21,158,120,32,215,91,151,85,201,130,35,227,113,79,8,247,3,219,30,212,117,168,58,19,118,29,83,94,143,181,165,87,139,154,73,49,194,112,133,56,54,238,228,31,56,7,207,138,61,191,255,0,135,222,179,209,90,54,69,233,23,11,84,219,140,8,170,148,237,186,51,47,168,164,36,18,164,37,226,144,218,220,1,42,249,124,237,32,28,241,87,14,175,129,182,212,224,47,107,122,255,0,114,169,219,211,170,30,9,107,9,211,159,79,238,21,120,10,5,89,24,38,189,237,208,191,74,92,163,198,245,27,100,200,113,45,250,142,28,33,25,56,201,62,194,182,67,233,126,9,74,82,222,229,57,234,5,37,60,144,71,108,251,86,155,189,48,6,212,231,57,221,230,159,189,212,91,46,32,50,120,165,183,2,182,219,199,214,145,72,52,234,115,66,211,28,241,89,72,207,138,244,104,33,42,5,64,145,244,172,188,80,167,9,66,74,83,224,103,181,37,247,178,233,172,182,229,104,145,197,22,116,77,118,223,254,72,183,51,117,74,191,9,45,102,55,168,132,161,78,48,181,165,73,109,196,5,252,133,73,89,65,1,95,41,198,13,9,226,182,109,36,172,109,206,236,241,142,244,56,92,16,147,70,234,203,116,98,255,0,168,63,203,234,147,104,147,42,60,233,19,4,115,112,101,180,57,42,51,73,224,250,101,92,37,67,182,6,42,198,105,190,163,221,236,31,10,242,237,26,145,201,23,189,110,155,220,123,141,190,229,62,224,235,141,34,51,72,82,127,14,184,227,33,74,86,245,41,78,43,201,72,0,99,38,14,248,30,154,157,71,166,29,97,247,94,83,201,148,225,116,149,99,36,144,73,56,228,231,35,205,91,91,183,70,98,217,180,204,27,131,205,160,182,165,151,93,231,27,208,210,75,139,3,220,224,1,143,57,172,101,109,89,167,168,49,128,55,61,183,90,202,46,154,42,105,132,175,38,195,196,128,186,96,104,184,247,174,153,218,99,76,140,35,148,181,234,33,230,112,135,35,169,99,156,31,9,61,138,123,16,7,144,8,101,137,209,25,175,45,162,166,160,205,101,183,10,155,113,232,69,74,112,118,36,43,118,56,192,253,213,46,198,234,142,134,212,221,57,177,46,195,96,212,218,198,68,240,162,184,150,38,209,46,98,210,19,156,34,57,218,66,145,133,5,32,171,113,63,40,0,241,93,189,17,32,106,139,141,170,214,171,173,190,194,234,76,137,48,111,80,156,140,171,116,191,148,37,14,33,92,180,226,147,144,164,123,164,31,25,52,81,54,160,94,196,140,241,207,225,105,228,109,49,177,176,56,249,113,140,161,40,186,102,124,205,137,152,148,56,150,82,158,22,62,68,129,219,8,0,14,49,231,61,133,51,107,214,140,8,175,41,11,43,36,115,159,53,100,245,117,162,12,189,18,137,113,144,24,125,177,178,74,56,249,84,61,190,135,250,85,107,234,172,164,65,101,229,149,28,161,4,243,218,161,206,37,214,53,155,221,76,139,220,251,178,88,45,101,81,117,123,106,131,241,21,165,174,209,39,126,138,145,250,85,166,85,45,13,21,41,5,223,213,238,218,146,10,142,14,54,228,103,183,25,205,90,254,179,107,199,52,55,78,30,189,222,86,8,176,105,169,204,60,208,7,99,42,97,40,244,82,128,123,2,178,132,164,19,159,155,243,170,153,171,99,197,157,173,97,170,231,48,219,225,126,150,140,236,137,56,207,164,210,86,55,171,255,0,80,9,39,28,224,28,83,183,199,231,94,173,9,208,238,105,43,29,222,201,124,85,230,88,146,235,182,169,98,76,113,20,29,224,2,9,219,185,192,217,9,81,42,30,151,222,180,113,192,233,221,12,125,179,229,159,250,178,162,168,83,178,162,78,248,243,59,126,2,167,166,52,104,205,71,105,135,28,112,132,0,225,82,66,64,80,30,43,57,67,113,94,10,108,41,74,35,98,247,114,156,30,70,43,66,162,227,187,212,156,115,94,130,11,178,91,46,33,167,22,128,118,238,3,140,158,194,182,171,14,69,134,233,186,149,42,68,83,169,244,169,99,52,177,91,52,160,149,12,131,143,56,161,22,88,8,36,100,3,143,202,189,223,181,203,133,26,44,135,98,202,101,137,169,82,163,58,182,84,148,72,9,86,213,20,40,140,40,5,12,29,164,224,240,121,173,75,164,39,104,36,36,28,142,104,155,88,117,183,86,117,7,67,105,61,51,123,212,55,59,166,158,208,172,191,31,79,219,223,119,115,22,134,222,112,56,234,90,24,224,41,96,19,146,123,12,96,113,72,111,194,228,234,186,151,126,0,53,32,180,107,137,176,30,249,125,96,151,82,21,192,62,15,242,21,117,250,241,212,22,78,157,179,64,229,107,104,122,237,148,44,163,211,81,4,21,100,16,71,7,28,119,205,124,201,233,134,188,115,68,235,184,87,16,181,37,180,168,54,231,61,146,124,253,142,13,95,157,42,245,179,172,122,61,151,37,23,29,79,225,23,25,223,73,239,77,198,247,12,161,104,86,15,33,64,125,179,200,172,111,93,165,181,91,103,118,205,63,117,176,232,85,167,252,87,211,52,124,89,30,168,251,162,157,76,118,220,241,117,23,246,109,183,6,221,15,174,236,144,181,75,109,32,109,40,109,64,131,146,60,146,48,64,57,162,61,83,214,123,62,157,185,56,165,93,174,242,20,233,10,47,122,65,221,199,234,1,207,240,53,15,244,103,75,216,180,58,29,110,245,106,184,206,184,180,179,181,225,27,241,10,41,207,24,192,227,2,167,61,53,98,180,245,24,70,85,190,197,50,20,93,163,114,164,179,233,188,231,254,221,136,31,65,227,247,212,89,132,13,101,175,113,253,232,173,224,97,112,14,184,14,182,51,251,9,247,167,157,113,99,168,58,118,83,17,164,45,214,247,169,163,188,108,41,82,71,39,7,183,223,243,168,147,171,247,31,197,45,220,40,129,207,36,118,31,210,167,61,81,10,38,153,178,50,204,56,108,69,244,26,41,82,210,144,51,159,239,138,172,253,89,213,241,209,34,70,245,182,86,128,113,206,126,248,170,185,70,185,134,148,243,94,98,128,235,42,190,117,77,211,50,252,26,64,80,7,36,253,42,26,235,4,54,172,58,170,52,198,99,22,158,120,37,106,91,96,37,36,128,50,49,142,255,0,95,53,51,164,171,82,234,153,14,140,169,166,135,206,82,50,62,128,31,175,20,195,213,222,150,47,83,66,68,84,171,211,148,143,214,37,88,224,43,7,32,253,57,199,216,86,174,133,226,7,134,56,241,186,197,86,48,206,211,35,123,170,246,244,231,100,169,73,89,200,113,207,83,24,250,98,187,83,126,49,180,242,224,37,181,5,56,240,116,185,187,216,112,49,78,77,244,171,80,126,53,108,181,107,152,251,237,168,167,99,109,149,149,0,50,84,49,220,99,205,15,73,203,50,75,110,37,72,113,39,10,73,24,82,72,238,8,60,131,87,224,7,88,133,72,64,39,72,225,112,142,252,115,91,4,113,142,245,129,148,86,233,32,3,239,79,167,172,147,77,165,215,8,82,130,6,59,145,154,76,54,146,172,40,227,235,88,243,74,132,89,110,28,9,80,224,113,244,167,15,211,9,85,177,76,150,227,16,49,180,250,99,113,251,211,101,42,44,145,205,190,87,77,198,98,37,148,20,54,148,96,96,224,99,53,43,252,61,252,73,61,211,167,154,133,56,173,113,18,54,37,204,146,66,125,143,210,128,58,121,210,77,87,213,217,55,86,116,158,152,212,58,161,235,21,177,251,213,201,187,77,185,217,170,183,192,99,111,173,45,224,218,79,166,203,123,147,185,106,194,70,225,207,52,196,192,10,78,120,32,242,61,141,71,168,130,57,152,99,126,233,218,121,93,19,195,163,54,33,125,56,232,231,92,109,218,146,201,21,200,78,197,125,215,182,145,185,67,129,231,247,84,243,167,250,219,23,76,60,209,113,200,193,180,141,216,40,25,88,224,119,199,122,248,231,163,245,181,219,66,77,18,109,147,29,97,64,238,217,156,160,159,168,169,211,165,157,65,215,125,126,117,171,106,117,5,146,219,184,109,11,152,29,43,88,231,246,66,115,207,220,86,106,78,142,218,114,94,28,52,248,254,149,251,122,204,147,1,25,7,87,22,253,171,119,241,63,241,141,105,128,135,155,97,109,254,38,78,228,180,210,87,130,72,28,156,119,199,61,254,149,84,225,106,11,159,84,239,254,155,33,215,253,95,144,45,9,42,5,94,6,59,146,124,36,121,169,30,219,240,81,18,36,212,175,81,223,230,95,166,128,146,176,218,63,14,192,63,84,229,75,80,199,24,42,3,233,83,103,74,116,44,13,8,200,102,207,22,60,44,124,171,125,45,164,59,183,29,130,191,216,63,46,245,22,57,169,97,37,204,248,143,117,34,74,74,202,157,165,248,90,56,64,186,91,225,233,205,25,98,108,72,111,18,192,245,75,39,149,52,162,59,184,123,111,250,15,217,252,251,5,234,13,32,243,218,137,123,80,85,233,35,3,142,234,63,216,171,96,205,182,60,152,233,111,0,140,99,145,128,163,253,42,24,248,137,184,194,233,244,83,6,34,155,114,241,112,66,150,178,15,205,13,163,198,243,255,0,146,185,218,15,128,79,129,158,97,247,181,19,233,143,119,20,245,99,233,168,105,12,179,27,53,191,83,192,243,42,19,125,150,32,75,112,183,180,250,121,111,212,31,239,86,121,199,220,80,230,162,179,219,245,2,29,68,235,124,121,101,103,11,46,32,40,171,219,158,249,30,14,105,217,179,150,82,162,149,4,246,108,99,199,189,36,199,199,142,61,135,243,175,64,166,164,108,81,136,155,128,188,34,187,169,75,81,82,234,151,108,79,208,112,2,167,194,150,43,118,148,151,0,41,82,84,159,116,156,138,61,214,122,71,167,214,222,131,232,187,189,143,88,222,174,125,66,184,202,158,214,167,211,178,108,134,52,75,43,45,173,63,131,122,60,189,228,72,14,160,157,201,192,82,84,20,48,0,5,113,92,240,44,189,24,184,11,95,149,31,224,214,118,241,94,168,72,81,255,0,186,61,234,143,72,244,230,133,233,87,79,47,214,126,162,88,53,101,227,87,193,149,38,247,96,135,17,246,102,104,247,154,120,54,134,36,169,127,35,133,212,157,233,82,49,194,85,198,54,169,65,120,4,3,202,87,60,2,1,229,71,184,218,146,84,64,0,100,147,226,139,220,233,228,142,145,117,82,205,109,234,110,150,214,54,104,45,200,133,54,237,106,118,58,237,55,105,22,215,74,29,37,143,196,55,242,41,214,9,45,56,164,41,7,114,85,133,10,20,216,28,73,73,25,10,24,35,222,139,122,181,214,157,101,241,1,170,145,125,215,90,174,255,0,171,239,77,196,102,2,103,222,103,57,50,82,99,178,157,173,53,189,100,157,137,25,192,247,36,242,73,37,28,73,216,97,35,129,59,12,39,109,117,213,139,102,130,235,70,181,159,209,123,166,191,208,218,38,248,153,86,184,76,203,188,150,174,175,90,31,9,11,135,53,216,197,40,117,11,198,20,222,84,146,2,65,220,70,76,125,144,223,0,0,49,140,15,21,34,252,45,252,66,61,240,173,214,235,94,183,137,164,244,62,184,122,212,204,150,69,159,88,90,5,214,209,36,62,194,217,42,118,57,82,119,41,1,123,146,115,194,128,239,65,22,235,122,181,13,245,166,82,150,153,92,199,246,225,180,108,67,123,149,156,37,35,178,70,120,30,0,2,185,102,116,219,215,186,224,89,151,191,28,163,46,153,104,38,181,51,73,149,45,14,126,21,158,49,156,122,170,254,131,249,209,20,200,110,116,202,254,197,198,40,88,181,173,96,57,130,73,140,174,219,179,255,0,19,68,246,123,123,54,120,8,143,28,0,203,8,8,72,174,169,205,250,240,148,143,77,46,229,4,148,145,156,224,112,49,82,141,43,93,25,141,220,172,137,235,82,54,168,78,211,176,225,88,14,144,107,136,186,130,194,194,253,98,254,71,252,240,62,254,106,75,179,92,246,41,9,65,27,60,1,216,85,48,233,118,164,153,164,111,126,164,22,140,187,44,213,250,141,169,10,249,161,168,228,169,10,30,18,15,24,238,147,145,128,49,83,2,186,242,244,8,225,17,8,117,245,0,2,136,202,80,125,241,231,251,239,88,90,142,131,82,103,49,196,47,227,194,245,74,111,107,40,99,165,19,84,60,3,108,100,249,91,63,133,57,245,39,174,49,58,79,99,220,125,57,87,137,45,255,0,164,140,72,41,71,179,174,243,144,128,123,14,234,35,3,3,36,86,91,181,238,86,170,185,191,46,225,33,249,79,190,178,244,151,156,86,86,241,250,231,249,118,3,129,197,115,204,149,42,255,0,53,201,115,159,113,247,223,229,78,56,173,202,87,24,201,254,248,175,70,24,222,210,66,19,132,172,231,24,236,145,253,127,238,182,125,39,164,71,67,29,178,243,147,248,30,11,202,61,164,246,154,110,173,61,200,211,27,127,213,191,147,220,253,176,57,39,46,5,56,128,226,147,140,124,163,233,244,21,228,160,150,211,130,63,104,251,98,186,100,160,129,187,3,229,28,12,121,174,103,202,153,25,81,7,110,79,25,237,86,246,89,144,110,84,1,241,53,241,27,122,248,176,235,61,203,93,234,75,102,150,182,222,174,236,70,102,75,90,126,208,213,170,18,203,12,33,144,224,97,191,148,56,176,128,165,145,221,68,224,1,128,57,190,30,174,125,60,181,117,146,199,35,170,118,125,89,125,208,45,173,193,118,133,166,231,179,6,232,234,11,106,8,44,186,234,84,128,82,225,66,138,78,55,4,148,238,78,115,65,57,194,6,15,57,237,71,183,13,117,161,165,252,55,90,180,228,126,159,191,23,169,16,245,3,211,230,107,68,234,7,150,213,194,216,182,118,162,222,171,114,145,233,33,77,186,18,176,250,22,9,27,129,7,118,83,70,89,102,233,106,245,183,54,195,72,65,114,153,140,228,167,140,80,240,143,234,47,209,14,148,151,67,123,142,208,178,144,18,85,183,25,192,3,57,199,21,160,142,7,214,182,142,222,192,84,78,1,226,164,62,135,244,239,65,235,203,94,184,115,91,117,45,61,59,149,98,211,146,46,122,113,149,105,201,55,129,170,110,72,35,211,182,110,97,67,240,165,193,217,229,130,129,201,60,3,149,115,180,139,148,164,134,139,149,28,150,195,67,39,129,82,36,255,0,136,72,211,254,20,109,253,47,29,60,233,219,50,224,106,87,53,17,214,141,218,202,117,68,132,45,149,53,248,7,37,110,249,162,13,219,131,120,238,132,112,8,36,199,75,112,184,6,70,7,183,181,32,7,212,82,150,222,215,65,110,171,120,44,103,142,216,162,142,146,219,255,0,17,170,145,33,67,45,196,5,89,199,251,143,3,248,102,134,125,50,78,7,53,37,232,43,50,172,182,180,5,39,231,41,83,142,251,140,227,143,176,167,162,109,220,171,250,164,161,144,17,201,217,29,54,55,54,161,140,2,188,12,125,133,56,37,3,122,185,63,41,199,240,255,0,246,184,44,141,250,177,25,29,200,86,9,247,0,241,205,58,32,102,20,151,48,6,199,10,127,118,42,200,109,101,231,242,13,236,154,110,86,166,32,223,92,117,76,169,40,124,239,113,109,228,16,175,59,177,252,233,226,209,57,166,27,81,105,178,161,229,120,39,159,108,227,189,122,61,27,241,19,214,65,193,83,57,79,239,175,75,59,10,144,232,88,24,105,42,33,25,247,247,254,148,173,219,9,183,157,64,95,132,226,10,220,108,37,125,222,56,87,61,135,176,174,219,98,242,183,9,25,9,87,167,251,187,215,50,29,44,48,167,22,14,198,193,207,60,240,43,123,91,42,106,3,69,71,4,141,231,234,79,53,208,81,203,87,172,151,48,121,28,19,199,253,87,36,193,177,99,0,238,119,228,31,114,43,174,72,32,53,128,146,74,187,119,197,115,203,202,238,81,144,66,176,50,178,63,46,7,243,162,233,27,149,255,217]}}
```

But I am getting this(**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"**) error.

Comment: The response you're receiving is not JSON/JSONP

Comment: put a break point in c# code and check if alls good dere

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't get your comment

Comment: @AtishDipongkor: The returned data does not look like jsonp. See accepted answer here for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683114/sending-jsonp-vs-json-data

Comment: But when I didn't use jsonp, then I got this error 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8064/CarService.svc/carservice/car/1. Origin http://localhost:3463 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. @Tewr

Answer (score 0):

If your service does not originate on the same host, one way is to use jsonp to circumvent this. But jsonp != json. You must modify your webservice to return a callback padding your json, to make it a jsonp.

Here's an example of how to set it up with MVC3: [ASP.NET MVC 3 JSONP: Does this work with JsonValueProviderFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795201/asp-net-mvc-3-jsonp-does-this-work-with-jsonvalueproviderfactory)