# JQuery was not Called

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am getting errors on callBacks. I have tried following code in jsfiddle.com . You can also try. Data from servelet is not returning. It's returning same error again and again. Check jquery library when you try in jsfiddle

```
 $.ajax({
            url : 'http://192.168.16.111:8081/MiddleWareUsman/androidServlet',
            type : "post",

         dataType: "jsonp",
            data : {
        "fname": "chaaaaapiio",
            "lname": "gya"
            },
            success : function(data) {
                alert("hello"+data);

            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        alert(thrownError);                     
            }
        });
```

My server side:

```
                    String a=request.getParameter("fname");
        String b=request.getParameter("lname");

        response.getWriter().write(a+" "+ b);
```

Comment: What error is it returning?

Comment: error: Jquery=121212121212121213345634 was not called. Error is about callbacks

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a couple problems.

1. JSONP requests can't be sent via POST.   They are actually sent as `<script>` tag requests anyway which are GET requests.
2. Your server isn't doing JSONP.  For the server to do JSONP, it must wrap the requested data in a call to a javascript function who's name was passed as an argument to the request and then the actual data is passed as an argument to that function.  JSONP is a big hack, but it works by requesting a javascript and that's what the server must return.

Comment: where should i change code bro. I am not getting it..Should i change my server side code?

Comment: @user3118495 - Change your ajax call to a GET and then change your server to output JSONP.  You will have to do some research on the easiest way to do that in your server environment.  Here's one [helpful description of JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about).

Comment: @user3118495 - in case you didn't realize, your server is NOT reachable from where we are out on the internet so the jsFiddle doesn't help us much.

Comment: @jfreind request parameter are reaching server. But response is not shown back. Instead it is showing same error

Comment: @user3118495 - that's because your server is NOT returning JSONP.  Not much else I can tell you.  If you request JSONP, the server must respond with JSONP.  A JSONP formatted response is VERY different from a JSON response.  JSONP is an actual script (a function call to a particular function name that was passed in the arguments to the server request) that the browser will then execute.

Comment: @user3118495 - we're not going to write your server code for you.  Do some of your own research on how to make your server environment produce JSONP.  Once you're doing that, you can come back if you have a specific problem with the JSONP.  If your server is `java` based (just guessing based on the tag), then you might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683114/sending-jsonp-vs-json-data).

Answer (score 0):

you simply can't send a `POST`  request using `JSONP`

check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) out to see how `JSONP` works..

Comment: what should i do then? you can try ajax  code in jsfiddle

Comment: please provide posting a link to jsfiddle

Comment: oh yeah, according to what @jfriend00 said, your jsfiddle is pretty useless

Comment: @jfreind request parameter are reaching server. But response is not shown back. Instead it is showing same error

Comment: what should i change in server side. Because request is printing on server but response is not getting back on page

Comment: i found that link but it's not helping