# I am doing a JSONP call to backend from javascript function in order to get the response data in json. How to do this from java end?

Tags: java, ajax, networking, jsonp

I am triggering the below crossdomain JSONP call from javascript using ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'https://xyz.abc.com/xxx/xxx/client', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp', 
  jsonpCallback: 'callback',
  data:{ id: '123456' },
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: 'application/jsonp'
});
```

Below are the Query string parameters as seen from the network tab:-

```
callback=callback&id=123456&_=1498907401152
```

But due to security and to prevent vulnerability I want to do this call from Java end. How can I do an equivalent JSONP call as posted above from java end? I am using a Struts2 action class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683114/sending-jsonp-vs-json-data) you read:

> JSONP is simply a hack to allow web apps to retrieve data across
>   domains. It could be said that it violates the Same Origin Policy
>   (SOP). The way it works is by using Javascript to insert a "script"
>   element into your page.

So when you want to use Java end, you don't need JSONP. Just do a JSON HTTP POST (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java)) in your action, process response and fill your action and return SUCCESS.